# Custom Master Page not visible while applying the theme in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, visual-studio-2012, theme

I have created a custom master page out of seattle master page by renaming it using SharePoint designer(I have also created a master page using visual studio). And then i made some modifications to it. When i go to `site settings > Look and Feel > Change the look > select theme > in Site Layout dropdown` i am not able to see the customSeattle master page option.

What needs to be done in order for that option to appear in there?

Comment: Make sure you check in and publish the master page. Are you able to see it in Look and Feel -> Master Page section where you change the master page?

Comment: The master page is checked in and published. Yes i am able to see the master page selected under Look and Feel -> Master Page .

Comment: check to make sure your custom page layout is referencing the right master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the .preview file in the location where my master page was residing. I took the seatle.preview file and renamed to my myCustomMAsterPagename.Preview and copied it to the located where the master page is residing.

Answer (score 1):

First go to Design Manager and check if your Master Page is published. IF its not publish it.

And also check if by chance you have your custom page in Site Pages. IF its there, move it to Pages library. Don't remember this exactly as I faced this issue once and did some changes on Library.